# Get filenames FSO with comparison of filenames to sort first by specific namestructure

Tags: vba, excel, automation, vlookup, filesystemobject

In the code below I could wrote a code to display filenames from a folder. The problem is now that I should display them in the correct Row. For now they are displayed in random sequence and that is not the purpose.

In column "A" the filenames to search for are called with similar name format **PBM12**.***T5***.***103***.

The actual filename to find is called with similar name format 1_29_**PBM_12_T5__103**.

I have to find a solution to compare **"only"** the **Fat marked letters and numbers like displayed here above**, without ***.*** or ***_***

As you will see **PBM12T5103** is returning in both namestructures.

Please don't try fixed length counts because the filenames are dynamic and the amount of letters are variable. The comparison of the SUBSTITUTED length of column "A" ( **PBM12T5103**) is the key to comparison but I can not handle to establish this comparison.

When the filename in column "A" has been found, in column "C" the **full filename** of  found file has to be displayed as the original format **1_29_PBM_12_T5__103**

Maybe a solution can be found when extra columns can be made to establish the comparison?

In Excel I could approach a solution, but this will not work automized like it should do.

I made the LEN(count dynamic), but this is still no solution to display the full filenames in the required row...

Hopefully somebody can help me out ..

```
Option Explicit
Sub fileNames_in_folder()
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Dim fldpath
Dim fld As Object, fil As Object, fso As Object, j As Long
 fldpath = "C:\"
  On Error Resume Next
   Thisworkbook.Sheets("1").Activate
   'start count row
    j = 11
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set fld = fso.getfolder(fldpath)
   For Each fil In fld.Files
'here I have to add an IF statement in order to compare the filenames written in column "A" with files from folderPath C:\" 
'When the correct files is found it should be displayed in column "C"
    If


   then
Cells(j, 34).Value = fso.GetBaseName(fil.path)
   End If    

'count behaviour
    j = j + 1
  Next
Columns("AH").AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: are there any rules in Column A filenames, like XXXYY.XY.XXX where X if for letter, X for numbers, first part is always 5 characters long with 3 left characters are only letters, etc? if so there is solution (you could provide these rules here), if not I don't think you could solve it easily.

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast KazJaw. The names are dynamic and there is no specific structure,thats why there has to be made a LENgt count comparison in the substituted filenames like I did in my excel workbook.That way the comparison will be dynamic and no matter wich names the filenames can be compared. But I can not handle to display the full filename in Collumn "C".In the excell I show how my knowledge would do this comparison,but maybe there exist a easier way to do that. Once the IF statement is established I should establish the THEN statement.Plaese let me know if something is unclear

Comment: so, some tips for you which could be helpful- using `Split function` you could divide your column A names into parts. Then you could try to use `InStr function` and check if each part exists within the original file name. For first part (PBM12) you will possible need `left function` or `right function` or some other (`mid` possibly). Finally, `Replace function` to get rid of underline mark.

Comment: I updated the formulas in collumn "C" a bit. This Collumn should show the result, but the problem now is that the Getfilenames are shown random, and not in the correct line. I check what I could do with the advise of KazJaw, but if anybody has any additional tips please let me know. This will take several weeks for me to figure all out... Any advise to solution is welcom..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you different way of getting file names. Instead of `FileSystemObject` let's use simple `Dir function` which allows to check the pattern of file name.

1) Files in my testing folder are as follows

[image]

2) I assumed that file pattern is as follows:

```
XXXY.Z.W
```

where:

```
XXX > 3 letters text 
Y > any length number/text 
Z > any length number/text 
W > any length number/text
```

3) The code of subroutine is placed in `2013-06-01...xlsm` file which you could see in the pic above (the same folder where your files are). Code is as follows (change where appropriate):

```
Sub solution()

    Dim j As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim fldPath
        'your path below
        fldPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
        ChDir fldPath

    Dim arrPattern As Variant
    Dim filName As String

    For j = 1 To Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        arrPattern = Split(Cells(j, "A"), ".")

        'I suggest to use different way of checking _
        pattern of file name. Pattern rules:
        '*YYY*XX*Z*W*

        filName = Dir("*" & Left(arrPattern(0), 3) & "*" & _
                            Mid(arrPattern(0), 4) & "*" & _
                            arrPattern(1) & "*" & _
                            arrPattern(2) & "*")
        If Len(filName) > 0 Then
            Cells(j, "B") = filName
        Else
            Cells(j, "B") = "not found"
        End If


    Next j

End Sub
```

4) results are presented in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Hi KazJaw, thanks for answering, but like I said in the beginning, fixed patters (or LEN counts) are not an option becouse the names as not Always the same. I just manage to find a solution for the dynamic nameformats. I will test it on several workbooks first to see If there are no bugs in it.I simplyfied VBA and maximised Excel. I will come back to it later. Thanks a lot for the suggestions.I appriciate a lot!

Comment: @user2151190, but there are some patterns I think- `PBM12.T5.103` could be `PBM_12_T5_103` but not `PBM_12_T_x_5_10_x_3`, am I right? if so the only thing to improve is the beginning of my solution (`XXXY`).

Comment: I have some issues too with the files where there are double __ , becouse fso.GetBaseName(fil.path) is not getting them by number , but random, then everything goes wrong.. The files are not found at this time. I should find a way to compare the substituted names in Collumn A with the substituted filenames and compare as many characters from "A" with the filenames, but I should start from the right side. This match should be made, than everything should be solved I guess?

Comment: Maybe we should Let getfilename do his thing (random enumeration in seperate collumn). Than maybe we could compare as much characters as the substitutes filemames in Collumn "A", with the right side of filenames in Collumn "seperate"? Is that possible in VBA?

Comment: did you tried the solution I've proposed? which % of files returns 'not found' message? Let's filter it in sheet, make a screen shot and add a link to see current status.

Comment: you need to adjust my code in terms of `fldpath` to the folder where you have your files. additionally I assumed that file names start as of cell A1, if not some portion of the code should be changed as well. Which line of the code you have an error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31048/discussion-between-user2151190-and-kazjaw)

Comment: How can be avoided that VBA is refusing to visual the name in row 9 of your example? .10 and .106 are different files... Is there a way to let VBA determinate that the (last) right nrs of the filenames that are written after the last _ (of filenames in searchfolder) are the effective file number?

Comment: there are a lot of VBA techniques which combination could be required in your situation, some experiments will be needed I think. Referring to `.10` or `.106`, if this number is last part of file name you could check `if left(filName, len(arrPattern(2)) = arrPattern(2) then`...

Comment: two advices- you need to find and describe all patterns of file names to deploy possible name comparison. you could try to explore `RegExp` which could be helpful in your situation. I don't have experiences to judge if this solve your problem. There are plenty of examples here in SO.

Comment: Thanks for your fairness KazJaw! Hopfully there is somebody who feels challenged enough to solve this mistery!

Comment: This discussion has been closed